# Can't set WKInterfaceButton title in table

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

I am developing a simple Watch App. I have an InterfaceController with a table. In that table, every row has a WKInterfaceButton. I have created a NSObject class with the button of the Table Row Controller, and created the outlet of the button from the interface to the NSObject class (called SuggestionMessageRow). I also gave an identifier to the Table Row Controller (MySuggestionRow). All the outlets and the storyboard stuff are setup.

Now, in the interface controller, I do the following:

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
[super awakeWithContext:context];

_suggestionsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"object1", @"object2", @"object3", @"object4", @"object5", nil];
[self loadTable];
}

- (void)loadTable{

[_myTable setNumberOfRows:_suggestionsArray.count withRowType:@"MySuggestionRow"];

for(int i = 0; i < _suggestionsArray.count; i++){

    NSObject *row = [_myTable rowControllerAtIndex:i];
    SuggestionMessageRow *myRow = (SuggestionMessageRow *) row;
    [myRow.myMessageButton setTitle:_suggestionsArray[i]];
    [myRow.myMessageButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor cyanColor]];
}
}
```

SuggestionMessageRow:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <WatchKit/WatchKit.h>

@interface SuggestionMessageRow : NSObject

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfaceButton *myMessageButton;


@end
```

This does not change the buttons title inside the table rows (they keep the title set on the storyboard button). HOWEVER, it sets the background color to cyan or whatever color I set, which tells me all the connections, outlets and so are correctly set up.

Any idea? I've checked in Apple Documentation but I have not found anything, feels like a silly/tricky problem :(. I tried to load the table on willActivate method but got the same result.

Comment: can u tell me how u gave action to WKinterfaceButton in table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, posting it just in case someone has the same issue. There was a lost/disconnected outlet of another button that I was not using anymore. Once I solved that, it works.